# This piece of code executes fine once and gives segmentation fault the other time

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, opengl

I have gems objects gems[10][10], which have an attribute color. I want to get three or more consecutive gems in a column having same color, and change thier color. The code below works just fine once while gives segmentation fault the other time. What cause the segmentation fault in random runs.

```
    bool findMatch(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;++i){      // To check ForVertical matchces
            for(int j=1;j<10;++j){
                int count=0;
                int a=0;
                if(gems[j][i].getColor()==gems[j-1][i].getColor()){
                    a=j;
                    count++;
                    while(gems[a][i].getColor()==gems[j][i].getColor() && a<10){
                        count++;
                        a++;
                    }
                }
             if(count>=3){
                 for(int x=j-1, itr=0;itr<count;++itr,++x){
                     gems[x][i].setColor(7);
                 }
                    glutPostRedisplay();
                 for(int x=j-1, itr=0;itr<count;++x,++loop){
                     gems[x][i].setColor(GetRandInRange(0,7));
                 };
                 return true;
             }
            }
        }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], presumably `x` in `gems[x][i].setColor` is out of bounds of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while(gems[a][i].getColor()==gems[j][i].getColor() && a<10){
```

When `a` reaches the value of 10, here. `gems[10]` gets evaluated before the `a<10` comparison. Since this exceeds the size of the array, this results in undefined behavior.